# Ant Replace Task - Windows vs Mac

Tags: xml, replace, ant, newline

I'm trying to use Ant's replace task to modify an xhtml file but am having a problem when building on MacOS. I have replicated the issue with the following minimal setup.

I have the following test text file

```html
    <div>
      <p>replace this</p>
    </div>
```

and the following build.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test.ant.replace" default="main">

    <target name="main">
        <replace file="test.txt">
            <replacetoken><![CDATA[<div>
      <p>replace this</p>
    </div>]]></replacetoken>
            <replacevalue><![CDATA[<div>
      <p>with this</p>
    </div>]]></replacevalue>
        </replace>
    </target>

</project>
```

The test file is formatted as CRLF. (In practice this is unpacked from a provided zip file so I'd like to keep it in the provided format)

- When I run the example using `ant -v` on Windows, the build works and
  the replacement takes place.
- When I run the example on MacOS it does
  not.
- If I change the test file format to LF, then it works on MacOS
  but not on Windows.

To allow developers on both platforms to run the build this implies I can't change the input test file's line endings via the FixCRLF task.

*Q. How can I change my replace task's replacetoken value to work on both platforms?*

Comment: You might consider bracketing your replace task with two [fixcrlf tasks](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html). One to ensure the format is suitable for the task and the second, if needed, to ensure the format is correct for subsequent use.  First one only might be enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I change the format to, for example, LF then the build in windows doesn't work. I suppose I could run the task against the original CRLF file, switch to LF, run the task again, then switch back to CRLF, but... yuk.

Comment: (Obviously I don't fully understand the context!) I had in mind to use fixcrlf with no args, which should "localise" the line endings for the host OS, whatever it is, so the replace always works.  A second fixcrlf would only be needed if the file must be in CRLF after that step.